# How I import createAppContainer from react navigation in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation

I working on a project add I will import this package ,I find this package on a YouTube video

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

and than I got this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-navigation'
  1 | import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
> 2 | import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
  3 | import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

Similar question is available on stack overflow but that is not related to create app container that is only for react navigation
So that's why I will post this question again

Answer (score 0):

`createAppContainer` is from React Navigation v3 and is not recommended as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/app-containers/) . The current version of React Navigation is v6, follow the instructions as given [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/). The video you watched is probably an old video.
If you want to use v3 itself in your app, make sure you install react navigation v3 and check it in your `package.json` file.